# open API spec to Odata raml conversion in mule4

Tags: mule, odata

I need to expose the rest API as OData service in Mulesoft. I have the below questions.

1. Is there an easy way/tool to convert openAPI spec to odata(RAML) to use it in APIKit router in mule4.
2. How we can define complex datatypes in odata.raml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use open api APIs directly with the last version of APKit and Studio without any conversions:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/platform/oas3

On the other hand I'm not sure if you are trying to use OData. That's a different standard. See the instructions for the OData plugin: https://docs.mulesoft.com/apikit/4.x/creating-an-odata-api-with-apikit

Answer (score 0):

You cant define complex data types in odata.raml,  but you can now use apikit for odata 4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).